# SQL Table Counting and Joining

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have Table A, Column 1.

This table has values such as:

```
1
2
3
3
4
4
4
5
```

I have Table B, Column 2.

Which lists certain values, like:

```
1
3
4
```

I need a query to Count each unique value in Table A, but ONLY if that value is present in Table B.

So with the above, the end result would be:

1 has a quantity of 1,
3 has a quantity of 2,
and 4 has a quantity of 3.

My only problem is that I do not have this ability. Any help out there?

Comment: You need query in **mysql** or **Sql server**

Comment: "Count each unique value", so you only want the total number of different values in the table? Or do you mean the number of occurences per value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, something like the following should solve your problem.

```
  select b.column1,
    count(a.column2)
  from tableb as b
        inner join tablea as a on b.column1 = a.column2
    group by b.column1
```

Since you wanted only records which are in both tables, I am using an inner join. Then I am just grouping by the ID found in tableb, and getting the count of rows in tablea.

Let me know if you have any problems.

For more information regarding inner join, see : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp, and for group by, see : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 1):

I would use an `INNER JOIN` query with `GROUP BY` aggregate function

```
SELECT a.column1, 
       count(a.column1) as total
FROM tablea a
     INNER JOIN tableb b
        ON a.column1  = b.column2
GROUP BY a.column1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**MsSql**

```
Select Distinct Column1,Count(Column1) Over (Partition by Column1) 
From Table1
Where Column1 IN (Select Column2 From Table2)
```

## [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6786a/18)

**MySQl**

```
Select Column1,Count(Column1)
From Table1    
Where Column1 IN (Select Column2 From Table2)
group by column1
```

## [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e92d/5)

Comment: I think you are missing a comma after `column1` in the first query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column1,COUNT(column1)
FROM table1
WHERE column1 IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT column2 FROM table2)
GROUP BY column1
```